# Telerik dropdownlist doesn't load in the grid class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, nopcommerce

I'm must create a nopCommerce plugin to implement some telerik gird with a dropdownlist as editable rows, the problem is that the plugin is a Class Library, not a ASP.NET MVC application and the Routing is done manually in a RouteProvider.cs file. So I folowed the example here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/clientedittemplates
And must have the following configuration:
My Model:

```
    public class ContentModel : BaseNopModel
{
    public string ContentId { get; set; }

    [NopResourceDisplayName("Plugins.Widgets.DiscountBanner.Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [NopResourceDisplayName("Plugins.Widgets.DiscountBanner.Content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [UIHint("DiscountsEditor"), Required]
    public string Discounts { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult _SelectAjaxEditing()
{
    List<ContentModel> model = new List<ContentModel>();
    return View("Nop.Plugin.Widgets.DiscountBanner.Views.WidgetsDiscountBanner.Configure", _discountBannerSettings.contentGrid == "" || _discountBannerSettings.contentGrid == null ? new GridModel(model) : new GridModel(JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<List<ContentModel>>(_discountBannerSettings.contentGrid)));
}
```

My View:

```
      @{
        Layout = "";
    }
    @model Nop.Plugin.Widgets.DiscountBanner.Models.ConfigurationModel
    @using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.DiscountBanner.Models;
    @using Nop.Web.Framework;
    @using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;

    @using Nop.Services.Discounts;

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onEdit(e) {
        $(e.form).find('#Discounts').data('tDropDownList').select(function (dataItem) {
            return dataItem.Value == e.dataItem['Text'];
        });
    }
    </script>
    <table class="adminContent">
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle" colspan="2">
            DiscountBanner Plugin for sing-up and sales tracking script implementation on your site
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle">
                @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.ZoneId):
        </td>
        <td class="adminData">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ZoneId, Model.AvailableZones)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZoneId)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="adminTitle" colspan="2">
            @(Html.Telerik().Grid<ContentModel>()
            .DataKeys(keys =>
                {
                    keys.Add(model => model.ContentId);
                })
            .Name("discount-settings-grid")
            .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-left:0" }))
            .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                {
                    dataBinding.Ajax()
                        .Select("_SelectAjaxEditing", "WidgetsDiscountBanner")
                        .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "WidgetsDiscountBanner")
                        .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "WidgetsDiscountBanner")
                        .Delete("_DeleteAjaxEditing", "WidgetsDiscountBanner");
                }
            )
            .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Title);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Content);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Discounts);

                    columns.Command(commands =>
                        {
                            commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text);
                            commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text);
                        }).Width(180).Title("Commands");
                })
                .ClientEvents(events => events.OnEdit("onEdit"))
                .EnableCustomBinding(true)
             )
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And My custom View "DiscountsEditor.cshtml":

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using Nop.Services.Discounts;

@{
    var _discountService = Nop.Core.Infrastructure.EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IDiscountService>();
    var discounts = _discountService.GetAllDiscounts(null, true);
    List<SelectListItem> listDiscounts = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in discounts)
    {
        listDiscounts.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.Name, Value = item.Id.ToString() });
    }
}
@Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("Discounts").BindTo(listDiscounts)
```

From what could I tell is that telerik doesn't find my partial view DiscountsEditor.cshtml because the project is a class library and the route values are not the same, for the specific project I must make my views "Embedded Resource" so I can call them with the full name, the problem is that I can't configure Telerik Grid to use a partial view from somewhere else.

I tried to use a custom template like this:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Discounts)
                        .ClientTemplate(
                        Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("Discount").BindTo(listDiscounts).ToHtmlString());
```

But the template loads after I put some information in the grid and is not editable, if I want to edit it the dropdownlist transforms into a TextBox, I don't know what to do next, or if I can use another controller but to load the dropdown from the current view not a partial view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need copy your views to your output directory. Try change them to 'copy if newer'. You will also need to add a web.config file in your views folder.